# How to know the type of the PlainObjectBase in Eigen C++ Library?

Tags: c++, templates, eigen

I would like to know the basic data type of an Eigen::PlainObjectBase variable inside a function, preferably as a string. Consider the following example:

```
template<class Derived>
void myFunction(const Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>& matrix)
{
  // std::string basicDataType = ??? //basic dataType of Derived

}

Eigen::MatrixXd A;
myFunction(A); // should  print "double"

Eigen::VectorXf b;
myFunction(b); // should  print "float"

Eigen::Matrix<std::complex<float> > C;
myFucntion(C); // should  print "float". It would be also nice if I could know that it is "complex" and "float" :)
```

Answer (score 3):

`Derived` has a typedef `RealScalar` which is the underlying data type of the object. (Note that the typedef `Scalar` would give you `std::complex<float>` instead of `float`)
This code:

```
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

template<class Derived>
void print_name(const Eigen::PlainObjectBase<Derived>&)
{
    std::cout << typeid(typename Derived::RealScalar).name() << "\n";
}

int main() {
    print_name(Eigen::MatrixXd{});
    print_name(Eigen::MatrixXf{});
    print_name(Eigen::MatrixXi{});
    print_name(Eigen::MatrixX<std::complex<float>>{});
}
```

outputs

```
d
f
i
f
```

On my linux machine with clang 18.1.0. See [live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ef1zxaW7c). If you want to have a nicer string name, you can implement an overloaded function which gives you a nice string version of your type instead of relying on `typeid`. Or read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81870/is-it-possible-to-print-a-variables-type-in-standard-c).